# Add % to values in sliderbar ticks - Shiny dashboard

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

I tried to add % to values in sliderbar using post = "%" but it is not adding % to values in the ticks below sliderbar. Please help me to add % to values below sliderbar.

Please check the image for further clarification,
[image: Reference]

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

ui <- dashboardPage(skin = "black",
                    dashboardHeader(title = "test"),
                    dashboardSidebar(
                      sidebarMenu(
                        menuItem("Complete", tabName = "comp"))),
                    dashboardBody(
                      tabItems(
                        tabItem(tabName = "comp",
                                fluidRow(
                                  sliderInput("range_var", "", value = 1, min = 1, max = 10, width = '100%', post  = " %")          
                                )))))

server <- function(input, output, session) { 
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Thanks,
SJB

Comment: This might help https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/shiny-discuss/4UbZCa_zIA4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use some CSS to add the `%` manually:

```
dashboardBody(
  tags$style(type = "text/css", ".irs-grid-text:after {content: '%';}"),
  tabItems(...)
  ...
)
```